# Error importing in Delphi 2010 WSDL generated from ColdFusion

Tags: delphi, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, delphi-2010

I'm a novice with SOAP and WebServices.

Trying -for testing purposes- to import in RAD Studio 2010 (Delphi Update 4) any [very simple WSDL produced from ColdFusion 9 WebService](http://www.forta.com/cf/tips/syndicate.cfc?wsdl), I received immediately error message "syndicate.cfc SoapBindind is not a valid component name"

Details

```
[50074F4C]{rtl140.bpl  } Classes.TComponent.SetName (Line 12075, "Classes.pas" + 4) + $1D
[51495BA0]{soaprtl140.bpl} WSDLItems.InternalGetBindingOfType (Line 1324, "WSDLItems.pas" + 9) + $20
[51495CC3]{soaprtl140.bpl} WSDLItems.TWSDLItems.GetBindingOfType (Line 1344, "WSDLItems.pas" + 1) + $16
[51495E58]{soaprtl140.bpl} WSDLItems.TWSDLItems.GetBindingOfType (Line 1377, "WSDLItems.pas" + 2) + $8
[22E27CB7]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImpWriter.TWSDLInterfaceImporter.GetInterfaces (Line 2628, "WSDLImpWriter.pas" + 16) + $3A
[22E24B44]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImpWriter.TWSDLImporter.ImportInterfaces (Line 1442, "WSDLImpWriter.pas" + 6) + $12
[22E24618]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImpWriter.TWSDLImporter.Import (Line 1287, "WSDLImpWriter.pas" + 37) + $A
[22E2351C]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImpWriter.ImportWSDL (Line 900, "WSDLImpWriter.pas" + 9) + $9
[22E565B0]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImporterWizard.TWSDLImporterWizard.ImportWSDL (Line 173, "WSDLImporterWizard.pas" + 17) + $23
[22E57EAA]{dclsoap140.bpl} WSDLImporterWizard.TWSDLImporterWizard.Finish (Line 516, "WSDLImporterWizard.pas" + 6) + $2
[20940061]{coreide140.bpl} Wizard.TWizard.Show (Line 713, "Wizard.pas" + 30) + $C
[22E588C7]{dclsoap140.bpl} SoapIdeReg.TSOAPMenus.DoImportWSDLExecute (Line 91, "SoapIdeReg.pas" + 4) + $5
[5007570B]{rtl140.bpl  } Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line 12513, "Classes.pas" + 3) + $7
[502B1915]{vcl140.bpl  } ActnList.TContainedAction.Execute (Line 448, "ActnList.pas" + 8) + $2C
[502B26F0]{vcl140.bpl  } ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute (Line 1094, "ActnList.pas" + 7) + $8
[500755CF]{rtl140.bpl  } Classes.TBasicActionLink.Execute (Line 12442, "Classes.pas" + 2) + $7
[214CB9E1]{vclactnband140.bpl} ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.ExecAction (Line 1066, "ActnMenus.pas" + 6) + $D
[214CCEA7]{vclactnband140.bpl} ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 1748, "ActnMenus.pas" + 15) + $15
[214D0460]{vclactnband140.bpl} ActnMenus.TCustomActionMainMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 3474, "ActnMenus.pas" + 3) + $3
[214CB5A5]{vclactnband140.bpl} ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.CMItemClicked (Line 945, "ActnMenus.pas" + 3) + $4
[50295E70]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7062, "Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[5029A738]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9819, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[50295A94]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 6840, "Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[50299ED0]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.GetControlAtPos (Line 9563, "Controls.pas" + 4) + $76
[5029A5FB]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9776, "Controls.pas" + 101) + $1D
[5029A738]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9819, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[214CCF96]{vclactnband140.bpl} ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.WndProc (Line 1783, "ActnMenus.pas" + 25) + $4
[50299DD8]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9540, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50076408]{rtl140.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13015, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[5029098A]{vcl140.bpl  } Controls.FindControl (Line 3377, "Controls.pas" + 6) + $9
[502C8775]{vcl140.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 9760, "Forms.pas" + 30) + $1
[502C87BA]{vcl140.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 9790, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[502C8AE5]{vcl140.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 9927, "Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
[004369AE]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 200, "" + 8) + $FFFB
```

Any suggest?
Alex/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the WSDL importer for Delphi 2010.  I can duplicate your problem, but it seems to work as expected in Delphi XE.

I don't know if there is an easy work around.

Comment: @gobbo67: Did the solution in the Forum post work for you?  If so, you should add your own answer with a link to that post and accept it.